# Transferring files over qpid

Tags: qpid

I need to transfer a music files over large size using apache Qpid.

I have a read some blogs, where it mentions the file transfer is possible.

But could not find any examples on it.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
Harisha

Answer (score 1):

Files shall be segmented and transferred as blocks. 
QPID Messsaging API for sending message.setContent(buf,len);

At receiving  dataPtr = message.getContentPtr();
len = message.getContentSize(); to get the binary data